# Internal Links like arXiv Documents

Tags: pdftex, links, arxiv

I am trying to have my LaTeX files have internal links like [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) papers do, where they reference Theorem 3.2 and you click on it and it takes you there. I am using MiKTeX on Windows 7 compiling with pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX and have downloaded source files from ArXiv and compiled them, but my resultant PDF file does not have the internal links anymore.

I tried changing the compiler type to pdfTeX (I think I read online somewhere that this might work) but I got the error

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{amsart} undefined control sequence
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

In particular, what do I have to do, to download a random arXiv paper and compile it on my computer and get the links to work? (Or does the submission process rewrite the tex code for their own compilation? so that there is no universal way to do what I'm asking?)

Comment: You have to call `pdflatex`, rather than `pdftex`

Comment: Does the files include the `hyperref` package?

Comment: No, the random one I chose does not, It will do something like \ref{BG} and then later cite it, but the pdf generated by ArXiv DOES have the links, which is what is confusing me? And yes, I'm currently using pdflatex and it doesn't add them. Could it be the case that the ArXiv compilation process will take in the Tex code, rewrite it to use hyperref and output its result? Or something along those lines?

Comment: You need `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the document preamble to make the links active. arxiv may well be adding that.